# Wordpress mobile devices logo resize

Tags: css, media

Hi I'm having a small media queries problem. The logo on the website I am working on does not resize when on mobile devices. So I've tried to add the code below but it doesn't do anything. Is there a way to set it up so that it works on mobile devices as well?

link : http://eyeandretina.com.au/

```
.header_left a img
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width:612px;
}

media {

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100%;
    } 
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100%;
    } 
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100%;
    } 
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */ 
    .header_left a img {
        width:100px;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It seems to work in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Chrome allows you to view your page in different devices by its "device mode" in the inspect element devtool. In inspect element section you can see a "mobile" icon next to the element tab. When you click on it, the device mode will open up and you can choose the device in the top left. I checked you page using this feature in iPhone 6 plus device mode and the logo is resizing to 100px width according to your media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just go through your website link and I found
your this css is not calling

```
http://eyeandretina.com.au/wp-content/themes/medicenter/style/responsive.css?ver=4.1
```

this css is overwriting you current css.

try to do your all code in this responsive.css or make your style.css as a prioroty

```
http://eyeandretina.com.au/wp-content/themes/medicenter/style.css?ver=4.1
```

Comment: Well, I can't seems to find the responsive.css in the editor. I have just style/custom/rtl.css. 

Is there another location it could be? Thank you very much for replying.

Comment: just go to your website and go to page source, you can find your both css on line number 34 and 35, and I am unable to find your style/custome/rtl.css

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Mr. Go, that solve the problem. You just save me hours.

Comment: you are welcome, I need a favour, can you please accept my answer is useful to you, so I get reputation, and I need to ask a question with image and I just need 1 more reputation, so please